# Can I choose which mail accounts go to Notification Center on iOS 5

Tags: ios

We have a number of email accounts set up in Mail on our family iPad1, only a couple of which are mine. I have the iPad the most (and utilize it's deeper features most), and want to start benefiting more from Notifications Center. At this point, when I open up notification center it lists all new messages for all of the accounts stored on the iPad, which is distracting for me. I just want to see my new messages at a glance.

I've set just my accounts to fetch automatically every 15 minutes, but as soon as I've opened the mail app, then all of the other unread messages populate in the notification list. Is there any way to control which accounts get sent to Notification center?

I'm imagining no, but maybe someone has an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Mail configuration in Notification Center does not currently allow for the selection of individual email accounts (assuming that your device isn't jailbroken).